# Apache URL Rewriting for absolutely referenced resources

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have an Apache web server working as a proxy to a number of internal sites.
Until now everything was working well as all sites were working like:

> www.proxy.com/app01 -> www.some_other_server.com/app01

A new site needs to be accessed through the proxy, this has not been an issue, but all resources (images etc.) are absolutely located, rather than relative.
E.g.

> www.proxy.com/new_site -> www.some_new_server.com/new_site (works)
>   www.proxy.com/new_site/index.html ->
>   www.some_new_server.com/new_site/index.html (works)
>   www.proxy.com/new_site/image.png ->
>   www.some_new_server.com/new_site/image.png (does not work, as the image is located at www.some_new_server.com/image.png)

The internal site (new_site) cannot be modified, only the Apache proxy.

Can the Apache proxy be configured to rewrite the pages so that the resources are no longer relative? What other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the reverse proxy specifically for images (or whatever else) **before** the reverse proxy directives you have for everything else:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/new_site/(.*)\.(gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$ http://www.some_new_server.com/$1.$2
```